# Add radial gradient texture to each white part of another texture in shader

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

Recently, I have read article about sun shader ([XNA Sun Shader](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~menzel/index.php?seite=tutorials&id=1)) and decided to implement it using `OpenGL ES 2.0`. But I faced with a problem connected with shader:

I have two textures, one of them is fire gradient texture: [image: fire gradient texture]

And another one is texture each white part of which must be colored by the first texture:
[image: target texture]

So, I'm going to have a result like below (do not pay attention that the result texture is rendered on sphere mesh):

[image: result]

I really hope that somebody knows how to implement this shader.

Answer (score 0):

You can first sampling the original texture, if the color is white, then sampling the gradient texture.

```
uniform sampler2D Texture0; // original texture
uniform sampler2D Texture1; // gradient texture

varying vec2 texCoord;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( Texture0, texCoord );

    // If the color in original texture is white
    // use the color in gradient texture.
    if (gl_FragColor == vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0,1.0)) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D( Texture1, texCoord );
    }
}
```

Comment: Shader has to fill each white spot by whole gradient range (white color begins from the center and black color ends to the edge) as shown in result image.